# Are there other reasons for service broker to be disabled than a RESTORE DATABASE

Tags: sql-server-2005, mirroring, service-broker

We have a production database where service broker was disabled.
We have a profiler that logs every backup / restore operation. I cannot find any restore operation in its trace.
Are there any other reasons than a database restore for service broker to be disabled ?

Note that this database is mirrored using high-availability and a witness server. In the error log, I can find

```
2011-07-29  09:00:52.53 spid25s     Error: 1479, Severity: 16, State: 2.

2011-07-29 09:00:52.53 spid25s     The mirroring connection to "TCP://DB84200:5022" has timed out for database "XXX" after 10 seconds without a response.  Check the service and network connections.

2011-07-29 09:00:53.05 spid24s     Database mirroring is inactive for database 'XXX'. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.

2011-07-29 09:00:53.72 spid24s     Error: 1404, Severity: 16, State: 6.

2011-07-29 09:00:53.72 spid24s     The command failed because the database mirror is busy. Reissue the command later.
```

Can mirorring failure disable service broker ? Or maybe is it the opposite : mirorring fails because service broker is disabled ?

Any suggestion to solve this issue would be greatly appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

Service Broker provides automatic poison message detection. Automatic poison message detection sets the queue status to OFF if a transaction that receives messages from the queue rolls back five times.

Check the SQL Server Logs for the roll backs. 
This looks more like a mirroring error though.